# How to ignore contents of an environment imported from another file?

Tags: macros, programming

Consider the following scenario:

- I define a package `mypac.sty` as follows

```
% mypac.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01] 
\ProvidesPackage{mypac}[2020/10/08 v0.01 LaTeX package for my own purpose]  

\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{docmute}

\newcommand{\Question}[1]{#1}
\newenvironment{Answer}{}{}

\endinput 
% mypac.sty
```

- I have a lot of standalone files, for example, `item-01.tex` as follows. During the writing (developing) phase, I don't want to render the questions, so I redefine `\Question` to empty. It works!

```
% item-01.tex
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mypac}
\renewcommand{\Question}[1]{% intentionally made empty
}

\begin{document}
\Question{Solve $2x=4$.}
\Answer
$\begin{aligned}[t]
2x&=4\\
x &= 4-2 \\
  &= 2
\end{aligned}$\\
A lucky answer!
\endAnswer
\end{document}
```

- I want to create `questions.tex` that must only contain the questions and no answers. In other words, I want to comment the contents sandwiched in `Answer` environments.

```
% questions.tex 
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mypac}
\usepackage{comment}
\raggedbottom

\newcommand{\Input}[2][.]{%
    \renewenvironment{Answer}{\begin{comment}}{\end{comment}}%
    \input{"#1/#2"}}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \Input{item-01} 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

## Question

How to remove or disable or comment the contents of `Answer` environments defined in `item-01.tex` when the file is imported to `questions.tex`? I hope my question is understandable. Any other tricks are also welcome as long as my scenario can be accomplished.

Comment: \renewcommand and \renewenvironment are not the same thing.

Comment: well if `\renewcommand{\Question}[1]{}` then why don't you use that also in the second file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this what you want?

**mypac.sty**

```
% mypac.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01] 
\ProvidesPackage{mypac}[2020/10/08 v0.01 LaTeX package for my own purpose]  

\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{docmute}
\RequirePackage{comment}

\newcommand{\Question}[1]{#1}
\includecomment{Answer}%

\endinput 
% mypac.sty
```

**item-01.tex**

```
% item-01.tex

\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mypac}
\renewcommand{\Question}[1]{}% intentionally made empty
  
\begin{document}

\Question{Solve $2x=4$.}
\begin{Answer}
$\begin{aligned}[t]
2x&=4\\
x &= 4-2 \\
  &= 2
\end{aligned}$\\
A lucky answer!
\end{Answer}

\end{document}
```

**questions.tex**

```
% questions.tex 
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mypac}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
\excludecomment{Answer}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \input{item-01} 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```